# Can i have two versions of one App with different BundleIds and same display names?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

We've an Application which is already live and used by many users. Now that we've came up with newer Programming language and new backend. We have created a new version of the App with completely different programming language as the older one.

We have some users who are still using the older(Legacy services).
Is it possible to create a new App with **different bundleId** than the older App but the **same Display name** and also the **same Screenshots** in App store as the older App?

> According to App Store Review Guidelines,
>
> Don’t create multiple Bundle IDs of the same app. If your app has different versions for specific locations, sports teams, universities, etc., consider submitting a single app and provide the variations using in-app purchase.

The problem is, we also require the older App for some of our customers, who have not migrated to the newer services.

Does Apple allows to have exactly same looking apps with different bundleIds and same display name in App Store?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to set this new version up as a new app, you can even use the same screenshots. What you cannot re-use is the app name displayed to your customers on the App Store (Entered in App Store Connect). That is unique and you will get an error if you try to use the same name. You can of course use the same on device name (entered in Xcode).

As long as you do not spam the App Store with "copies" of the app, there should be no problem, I've seen this countless times and there are also some prominent examples of companies "phasing" out their old apps. It would probably appropriate to remove the "old" app from sale on the store in the mid- to long-term though.